# Product of Bernoulli variates

Tags: probability, products

I am stuck with something that looks very simple but I am not able to find where I am wrong. Let $\xi_k$ with $k=1,...,n$ be $n$ iid Bernoulli random variables such that

$$
\mathbb{P}\left[\xi_k=1\right]=p,~~\mathbb{P}\left[\xi_k=0\right]=1-p.
$$

The product

$$
\psi = \xi_1\,\xi_2\,\cdot\cdot\cdot\xi_n
$$

is stil a Bernoulli variable with either $\psi=1$ or $\psi=0$. Clearly $\mathbb{P}\left[\psi=1\right]=p^n$, therefore $\mathbb{P}\left[\psi=0\right]=1-p^n$. Where I am wrong if I say

$$
\mathbb{P}\left[\psi=0\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[\{\xi_1=0\}\cup\{\xi_2=0\}\cup ...\cup\{\xi_n=0\}\right]=n\,\left(1-p\right) ? 
$$

Comment: Union bound is not optimal in general, and our case is not an exception. More elementarily, probability splits primarily when events are disjoint (exclusive), and this is simply false for your events. Instead you may apply the inclusion-exclusion principle to reach the same conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that
$$
\Pr\{A\cup B\}=\Pr\{A\}+\Pr\{B\}-\Pr\{A\cap B\}=\Pr\{A\}+\Pr\{B\}-\Pr\{A\}\Pr\{B\}
$$
if $A$ and $B$ are independent events.
For example, if $n=2$,
\begin{align*}
\Pr\{\psi=0\}&=\Pr(\{\xi_1=0\}\cup\{\xi_2=0\})\\
&=\Pr\{\xi_1=0\}+\Pr\{\xi_2=0\}-\Pr\{\xi_1=0\}\Pr\{\xi_2=0\}\\
&=1-p^{2}.
\end{align*}
In general, we need to use the [inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion-exclusion_principle#In_probability).

Comment: thanks, now I realize is a typical mistake of mine: wrongly I assume that independence means $A\cap B=\emptyset$.